# How to check whether column is.numeric() inside the function call?

Tags: r

I am trying to write a small test that will check whether the column supplied is numeric

```
fun_df <- function(data,x){
   
  if(is.numeric(data$x){
    stop("done!")
  }
  print("did not pass")
}

fun_df(mtcars, dist)
```

what will be the best way to specify `is.numeric(data$x)`? i tried `{{x}}`, `!!x`. but I can't get the test pass. I specifically want to specify `fun_df(cars, dist)` and not `fun_df(cars, "dist")`

Comment: Use `data[, x]`.

Comment: does not work, gives me error `Error in .subset(x, j) : invalid subscript type 'closure'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `deparse(substitute())`.

```
fun_df <- function(data,x) {
  xx <- deparse(substitute(x))
  if(is.numeric(data[[xx]])){
    stop("done!")
  }
  print("did not pass")
}
fun_df(iris, Sepal.Width)

Error in fun_df(iris, Sepal.Width) : done!
```

Answer (score 1):

**Update:** see comments:

We do not need substitute:
We can use column name only:

```
fun_df <- function(data,x) {
  
  if(is.numeric(data[,x])){
    stop("done!")
  }
  print("did not pass")
}

fun_df(mtcars, "mpg")
Error in fun_df(mtcars, "mpg") : done!
```

**First answer:**
Additionally we could use `{{}}`: (thanks to deschen who solved the bracket issue(+1):

```
fun_df <- function(data, x) {

 i1 <- data %>%
         pull({{x}}) %>%
     is.numeric
 if(i1)  {
   print("done!") 
 } else
   print("did not pass")    
     
     
  
}

fun_df(cars, dist)
[1] "done!"
```

Comment: so now {{}} works?? i don't think so since you add column name in quotations fun_df(cars, "mpg") so of course it never be numeric

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: your x = "mpg"  (character value)- so  it will never pass a test that is.numeric("mpg" ) - it is always FALSE. {{}} works only if column name is specified without "" :fun_df(cars, mpg)

Comment: OK . Now I got it. Sorry didn't realized the real problem!  Please see my update. Try the above version with `"mpg"` and tell me please!

Comment: no, it will not pass the test, since r cant see that x belongs to data object, so it just do x="mpg", where class(x) is a character, so test fails

Comment: again, I think {{}} will never work if you specify column names in quotations.

Comment: I guess the issue is with `if(is.numeric({{x}}))`.  Your first solution works fine though

Comment: i..e you may need `fun_df <- function(data, x) {

 nm1 <- data %>%
     select(where(is.numeric)) %>%
     names
  if(x %in% nm1)  {
    print("done!") 
  } else
    print("did not pass")
};
fun_df(cars, "mpg")`

Comment: ,@akrun, This looks great again, dear master akrun. Learned so many things from you. I thank you!

Comment: @TarJae I think you may want the second to be `fun_df <- function(data, x) {

 i1 <- data %>%     
     pull({{x}}) %>%
     is.numeric
 if(i1)  {
   print("done!") 
 } else
   print("did not pass")    
     
     
  
}

fun_df(cars, dist)`

Comment: There is no "mpg" column in `cars`, is it a typo?

Comment: yes, this is what i realized that {{}} notation only works with tidy framework, so  `is.numeric({{x}})` will not work and only when  I do `i1 <- data %>%  pull({{x}})` will let me check if teh column is numeric

Answer (score 0):

1. You hvae a missing closing bracket in your function.
2. You probably want to do an if else combination.
3. If you are open to pass the variable name as a chararcter vector, then the following works:

---

```
fun_df <- function(data, x)
{
  if(is.numeric(data[, x]))
  {
    print("done!")
  } else
  print("did not pass")
}

fun_df(mtcars, "mpg")

[1] "done!"
```

Comment: thanks! but this is not applicable to my question, my column name is not in quotations